# Achieve same search result for synonym in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

For example I have two Entities called `Project` and `Technology`. Each instance of `Project` has ManyToOne relationship with Entity `Technology`. Now some Project has `JavaScript`, some has `javascript` and some has `JS`. And I am searching project using elastic-search.

What can be a feasible way, so that when user search with anyone from `javascript`, `JavaScript` and `JS`, user gets same search result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a task for synonyms, you need to apply [synonyms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html).

It could be done with something like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                        "filter" : ["synonym"]
                    }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `synonym.txt` should contain the data, in your case:

```
javascript, JavaScript, JS
```

it means, that this words are synonyms, and when user will search by them in the field, query will be expanded, if you're using match query.

After these changes, I would recommend to reindex your data.